# Automation - How to give Accessibility identifier for ActionSheet elements

Tags: swift, uikit, uialertcontroller

I need help to provide Accessibility identifier to the buttons in action sheet. I have 3 of them

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add new", style: .default, handler: ....))
actionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove", style: .destructive, handler: ....))
```

This is the code and I would like to set accessibility identifier to each of this "Add new" and "Remove" actions. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done it like below code by making action as let and then set identifier

```
 let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
 let newAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add new", style: .default, handler: {_ in })
 newAction.accessibilityIdentifier = "identifier"
 actionSheet.addAction(newAction)
```